# How to compare the values of one column? SQL(Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Postgres

I have table user_answers:

```
----------------------------
| id | user_id | answer_id |
----------------------------
|  1 |    47   |   121     |
----------------------------
|  2 |    47   |   125     |
----------------------------
|  3 |    47   |   141     |
----------------------------
|  4 |    49   |   122     |
----------------------------
|  5 |    49   |   121     |
----------------------------
|  6 |    49   |   101     |
----------------------------
|  7 |    52   |   121     |
----------------------------
|  8 |    52   |   125     |
----------------------------
|  9 |    52   |   101     |
----------------------------
| 10 |    67   |   101     |
----------------------------
```

I would like to get user_id, only user_id where answer_id = 121 and answer_id = 125.

A good result: 47 and 52
because:
user_id = 49 has 121, but no 125

This simple query does not work (returns nothing):

```
SELECT user_id FROM user_answers
WHERE answer_id = 121 AND answer_id = 125
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query returns nothing because `answer_id` has only one value on any given row.  It cannot have multiple values on the row.

This is an example of a set-within-sets query.  I would recommend using `group by` and `having`.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM user_answers
WHERE answer_id IN (121, 125)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT answer_id) = 2;
```

THis will return values that have 121, 125 and other values.  To get only those two values:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM user_answers
WHERE answer_id IN (121, 125)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(CASE wHEN answer_id = 121 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE wHEN answer_id = 125 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```

Comment: We should have a tag for this kind of problems. They come up on regular basis

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . More power to you.  I call them "set-within-sets".  I don't know if there is another name.

Answer (score 2):

```
select user_id
from user_answers
where answer_id in (121, 125)
group by user_id
having count(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need Or, not And.

```
SELECT user_id FROM user_answers WHERE (answer_id = 121 OR answer_id = 125)
```

Your original query is looking for results where answer_id is both 121 and 125 at the same time. Using OR looks for results where answer_id is either value.

Comment: For anyone wondering why this is not a complete solution in comparison to the accepted one. This will return *any* `user_id` where `answer_id` is 121 or 125. So it will return `user_id` 49, which was specifically indicated in the question as a bad result because that user does *not* have both answers. To fix, a `group by` clause is necessary on the `user_id`. The `group by` then allows to tally up with `count(*)` how many rows the `user_id` is present in. All that's left now is to filter out  with a `having` clause any `user_id` that is counted less than twice (once for each 121 and 125).